# Perform chi-test without using chisq.test function?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which I want to observe if there is a relationship between salaries and gender (two categorical varibles). The only condition is that I cannot use the R function chisq.test. I have tried to design the following function, but I do not get really favorable results.

```
lchisq <- function( x, y ){
n00 <- sum( (x==0) & (y==0) )
n11 <- sum( (x==1) & (y==1) )
n01 <- sum( (x==0) & (y==1) )
n10 <- sum( (x==1) & (y==0) )
cat("Table values:", n00, " ", n01, " ", n10, " ", n11, "\n")
nx0 <- sum( x==0)
nx1 <- sum( x==1)
ny0 <- sum( y==0)
ny1 <- sum( y==1)
cat(nx0, " ", nx1, " ", ny0, " ", ny1, "\n")
total = sum(nx0, nx1)
e00 <- (nx0*ny0) / total
e01 <- (nx0*ny1) / total
e10 <- (nx1*ny0) / total
e11 <- (nx1*ny1) / total
cat("Expected values:", e00, " ", e01, " ", e10, " ", e11, "\n")
chisq <- (n00-e00)^2 / e00 + (n01-e01)^2/e01 + (n10-e10)^2/e10 + (n11-e11)^2/e11
df <- 1
cat("chisq: ", chisq)
return (chisq)
}

a=0.05
lchisq(df$gender, df$salary)
```

and I get the following:

```
Table values: 438   0   0   0 
438   0   438   0 
Expected values: 438   0   0   0 
chisq:  NaN[1] NaN
```

I can't post samples because of data privacy but I can put an example.

```
SALARY GENDER
high   female
high   male
medium male
low    female
```

Any idea of what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use real data. Just make some up. Here is an example that you can convert into a function:

```
(Observed <- matrix(c(27, 15, 11, 33), 2, 2, dimnames=list(Sex=c("Female", "Male"), Salary=c("High", "Low"))))
#         Salary
# Sex      High Low
#   Female   27  11
#   Male     15  33
(Expected <- as.matrix(rowSums(Observed)) %*% colSums(Observed) / sum(Observed))
#            [,1]     [,2]
# Female 18.55814 19.44186
# Male   23.44186 24.55814
(ChiSq <- sum((Observed - Expected)^2/Expected))
# [1] 13.4476
(df <- (nrow(Expected) - 1) * (ncol(Expected) - 1))
# [1] 1
(p <- pchisq(ChiSq, df, lower.tail=FALSE))
# [1] 0.0002453194

(check <- chisq.test(Observed, correct=FALSE))
# 
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
# data:  Observed
# X-squared = 13.448, df = 1, p-value = 0.0002453
# 
check$expected
#         Salary
# Sex          High      Low
#   Female 18.55814 19.44186
#   Male   23.44186 24.55814
```

Comment: Hey @dcarlson Your code looks good, and to see if there is a relationship between gender and having a rich salary, how should I modify the code you have proposed?

Comment: The null hypothesis is that there is no difference, the Chi Square value is zero. The p-value tells you how likely this Chi Square value would be if the real value was zero. Since the p-value is .0002, it is very unlikely to come from data where there is no difference in salary by gender. Once you have chosen the p-value that will indicate rejection of the null hypothesis, just compare that to the computed value. If the computed value is less than the chosen significance level, reject the null hypothesis and conclude the relationship is significant.